# How do i turn on and off location service?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am developing an app to track myself on a google map using fused location provider and Now i want to have a button on action bar to turn on/off the location services.

I tried following code but it says its depriciated. Are there better ways to do this??

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can execute similar code only on root phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i want to have a button on action bar to turn on/off the location services.

Your code does not attempt to "turn on/off the location services". It attempts to enable and disable the location services. Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. The user can enable and disable whatever location technologies the user wants, through the Settings app or perhaps through other device-specific means.

Your app controls whether it receives, or does not receive, location updates through `LocationClient`. The Play Services engine, in turn, will use that information to determine whether the GPS radio needs to be powered on or not.

Comment: thanks you are truely awesome , i know exactly what i have to do now :D